# Conditionally appending values

Tags: jquery, append, indexof

In my application, I have a form with some `Text Inputs`. The value of these inputs will always be a link.

Some of my `Links Inputs` already contain `?utm....`.

When users are adding links, I have an `input` field where they can insert their `utm` and click on <kbd>Set UTM to Links</kbd> button and it will append/add their `utm` to all of the `Link Inputs`.

What I want to achieve is when clicking on <kbd>Set UTM to Links</kbd>, **only** links that don't contain `?utm....`, append/add the `utm` to their value.

I have tried it with the snippet below. What I have now, appends the `utm` to **all** the links:

```js
  $(".set_utm_value_input").click(function () {
    var utmValues = $('#set-input-utm').val();
    $("input[class='links']").each(function() {
      $(this).val(function() {
        return this.value + utmValues;
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
input{width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="form-control" id="set-input-utm" type="text" value="?utm_">
<button class="set_utm_value_input" style="margin-top: 25px;margin-left: -32px;">Set UTM to Links</button>

<input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
<input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link2.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
<input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link3.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
```

I have also tried it with the snippet below. This almost does the job, but the only thing wrong is that if `value` doesn't contain any `utm`, it clears/empties the whole input/value.

```js
$(".set_utm_value_input").click(function () {
  var utmValues = $('#set-input-utm').val();
  $("input[class='links']").each(function() {
    $(this).val(function() {
      var inputValue = this.value;
      if (inputValue.indexOf('?utm') == -1){
        return this.value + utmValues;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input{width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control" id="set-input-utm" type="text" value="?utm_">
    <button class="set_utm_value_input" style="margin-top: 25px;margin-left: -32px;">Set UTM to Links</button>

    <input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link.com/path/">
    <input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link2.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
    <input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link3.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
```

Answer (score 0):

You `missed` to add `else part` `else { return this.value; }`

**Note :** `?utm` is not exists means it's go inside the if statement and `returning` this `return this.value + utmValues;` if already `?utm` exists your `not returning` anything that's why it's become `empty`

```
      if (inputValue.indexOf('?utm') == -1){
        return this.value + utmValues;
      }else{
         return this.value;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }
```

```js
$(".set_utm_value_input").click(function () {
  var utmValues = $('#set-input-utm').val();
  $("input[class='links']").each(function() {
    $(this).val(function() {
      var inputValue = this.value;
      if (inputValue.indexOf('?utm') == -1){
        return this.value + utmValues;
      }else{
         return this.value;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input{width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control" id="set-input-utm" type="text" value="?utm_">
    <button class="set_utm_value_input" style="margin-top: 25px;margin-left: -32px;">Set UTM to Links</button>

    <input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link.com/path/">
    <input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link2.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
    <input type="text" class="links" value="http://www.link3.com/path/?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=partner">
```